# Jena Fuseki on Mac M1 slow on loading multiple small turtle files

Tags: apple-m1, jena, fuseki

I am trying to load some data into Jena Fuseki 4.7.0 on my Mac M1 and noticed that loading multiple small files is very slow in comparison to linux machine.

Then I did some tests by loading a file with single triple below:

```
<http://ex.com/1> <http://ex.com/p> "Test".
```

Please note that for all the tests below I created a new dataset and then loaded the file using Fuseki UI. To rule out the possibility of slow Java start I load the file more than once in same dataset without clearing the dataset or restarting Fuseki.

Fuseki 4.7.0 TDB dataset on a VM(Standard D2s v5 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)) running in Azure I get times as below:

```
15:58:51 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 4.0 GiB
15:58:51 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   11.0.19
15:58:51 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Linux 5.4.0-1106-azure amd64


16:15:25 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3411] POST http://***:3030/test/data
16:15:25 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3411] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
16:15:25 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3411] 200 OK (71 ms)
16:16:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3412] POST http://***:3030/test/data
16:16:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3412] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
16:16:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3412] 200 OK (43 ms)
16:16:34 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3413] POST http://***:3030/test/data
16:16:34 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3413] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
16:16:34 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3413] 200 OK (51 ms)
```

Fuseki 4.7.0 TDB dataset on Mac M1 Max with 10 cores (8 performance and 2 efficiency) and 64GB RAM

```
17:26:48 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 4.0 GiB
17:26:48 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   11.0.18
17:26:48 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Mac OS X 12.6 aarch64


17:10:27 INFO  Fuseki          :: [217] POST http://localhost:3030/test/data
17:10:27 INFO  Fuseki          :: [217] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
17:10:27 INFO  Fuseki          :: [217] 200 OK (486 ms)
17:11:04 INFO  Fuseki          :: [218] POST http://localhost:3030/test/data
17:11:04 INFO  Fuseki          :: [218] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
17:11:04 INFO  Fuseki          :: [218] 200 OK (319 ms)
17:11:20 INFO  Fuseki          :: [219] POST http://localhost:3030/test/data
17:11:20 INFO  Fuseki          :: [219] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
17:11:20 INFO  Fuseki          :: [219] 200 OK (328 ms)
```

Fuseki 4.7.0 in mem dataset on a VM(Standard D2s v5 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)) running in Azure I get times as below:

```
14:33:04 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 4.0 GiB
14:33:04 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   11.0.19
14:33:04 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Linux 5.4.0-1106-azure amd64


14:51:20 INFO  Fuseki          :: [121] POST http://****:3030/test-in-mem/data
14:51:20 INFO  Fuseki          :: [121] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
14:51:20 INFO  Fuseki          :: [121] 200 OK (24 ms)
14:51:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [122] POST http://****:3030/test-in-mem/data
14:51:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [122] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
14:51:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [122] 200 OK (3 ms)
```

Fuseki 4.7.0 in mem dataset on Mac M1 Max with 10 cores (8 performance and 2 efficiency) and 64GB RAM

```
15:42:42 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 4.0 GiB
15:42:42 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   11.0.18
15:42:42 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Mac OS X 12.6 aarch64


15:47:58 INFO  Fuseki          :: [107] POST http://localhost:3030/test-in-mem/data
15:47:58 INFO  Fuseki          :: [107] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
15:47:58 INFO  Fuseki          :: [107] 200 OK (35 ms)
15:48:38 INFO  Fuseki          :: [108] POST http://localhost:3030/test-in-mem/data
15:48:38 INFO  Fuseki          :: [108] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
15:48:38 INFO  Fuseki          :: [108] 200 OK (13 ms)
```

Java version on M1 Mac

```
******** % java -version

openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (build 11.0.18+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (build 11.0.18+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Java version on Azure VM Standard D2s v5

```
******$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I have also tried with JDK17 and no luck. Please see the results below:

Fuseki 4.7.0 in TDB dataset on Mac M1 Max with 10 cores (8 performance and 2 efficiency) and 64GB RAM

```
openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.42+19-CA (build 17.0.7+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.42+19-CA (build 17.0.7+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
11:30:17 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 4.0 GiB
11:30:17 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   17.0.7
11:30:17 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Mac OS X 12.6 aarch64


11:30:55 INFO  Fuseki          :: [9] POST http://localhost:3030/test/data
11:30:55 INFO  Fuseki          :: [9] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
11:30:55 INFO  Fuseki          :: [9] 200 OK (661 ms)
11:31:01 INFO  Fuseki          :: [10] POST http://localhost:3030/test/data
11:31:01 INFO  Fuseki          :: [10] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
11:31:01 INFO  Fuseki          :: [10] 200 OK (315 ms)
11:31:26 INFO  Fuseki          :: [11] POST http://localhost:3030/test/data
11:31:26 INFO  Fuseki          :: [11] Filename: load-test.ttl, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
11:31:26 INFO  Fuseki          :: [11] 200 OK (342 ms)
```

Java is not running in emulated mode, please see the details below:

```
10:43:03 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 4.0 GiB
10:43:03 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   11.0.18
10:43:03 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Mac OS X 12.6 aarch64
10:43:03 INFO  Server          ::   PID:    29753
```

[image]

I have tried to search for it but could not find anything. It seems there is overhead of few hundred milliseconds regardless of the file size. I am wondering if anyone has any idea what could be the reason or how to debug it?

Comment: Even 51ms seems high. (these times are from the point the request is received to the point the response is sent). Are you using a TDB database? The storage layer will have a significant effect because there is a transaction and the operation itself is very little work. To isolate, try running the test with an in memory dataset "fuseki-server --mem /test".
For the M1 Mac, is it running the Java JVM in emulator mode?

Comment: @AndyS I was using TDB. I have tested with in mem dataset and added details in question. I was suspecting that it might be something to do with Java but I do not know if the JVM is running in emulator mode. Not sure how to check that. I am using AWS Corretto JDK at the moment but I also tried with Azul JDK. Documentation for both JDKs suggest that these are tuned to work with Mac M1. Is there any trace/debug or performance metrics I can enable in Fuseki to see what exactly is taking time?

Comment: The numbers suggest it's the POST request or (more likely) the disk access. Running many loads and using a Java profiler (VisualVM) might give some information.  There isn't any Fuseki logging at that level. The 661ms is, I assume, the first load attempt so class loading of some code, even then additional 400ms for the classloading is huge. (If it's not the first attempt, a variation of 400ms between this and the next attempt, for the same code path, is not something I can explain). Then cost around 300ms an operation compared to Azure is again something that is hard to explain.

Comment: Check: these tests aren't inside containers?

Comment: You may be better contacting other Mac M1 users. The Jena user list is users@jena.apache.org. To join this list, please send an email to: users-subscribe@jena.apache.org.

Comment: Re Check: Fuseki is running direct, no container.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the possibility of the JVM being emulated on your Mac please start up the Fuseki Server, then go Activity Monitor and find the associated `java` process.  There will be a **Kind** column that will say either `Intel` or `Apple`.  If it says `Intel` then you've installed a JVM that's not built for the Apple architecture so its running via Apple's emulation layer.

For example on my M1 MacBook I see the following process:

[image: Java process running with native architecture]

i.e. I have a JVM of kind `Apple` so that means it is running natively.  If yours says `Intel` in that column then you are running via emulation.

I then tried your test and got the following outputs:

```
09:46:31 INFO  Server          :: Apache Jena Fuseki 4.7.0
09:46:31 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_HOME=/Users/rvesse/Documents/Apps/fuseki-4.7.0/.
09:46:31 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_BASE=/Users/rvesse/Documents/Apps/fuseki-4.7.0/run
09:46:31 INFO  Config          :: Shiro file: file:///Users/rvesse/Documents/Apps/fuseki-4.7.0/run/shiro.ini
09:46:31 INFO  Config          :: Template file: templates/config-mem
09:46:32 INFO  Server          :: Database: in-memory
09:46:32 INFO  Server          :: Path = /ds
09:46:32 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 4.0 GiB
09:46:32 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   17.0.4
09:46:32 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Mac OS X 12.6.5 aarch64
09:46:32 INFO  Server          ::   PID:    3199
09:46:32 INFO  Server          :: Started 2023/05/02 09:46:32 BST on port 3030
09:51:58 INFO  Fuseki          :: [1] POST http://localhost:3030/ds/
09:51:58 INFO  Fuseki          :: [1] Body: Content-Length=44, Content-Type=application/turtle, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
09:51:58 INFO  Fuseki          :: [1] 200 OK (10 ms)
09:52:06 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2] POST http://localhost:3030/ds/
09:52:06 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2] Body: Content-Length=44, Content-Type=application/turtle, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
09:52:06 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2] 200 OK (2 ms)
09:52:11 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3] POST http://localhost:3030/ds/
09:52:11 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3] Body: Content-Length=44, Content-Type=application/turtle, Charset=null => Turtle : Count=1 Triples=1 Quads=0
09:52:11 INFO  Fuseki          :: [3] 200 OK (2 ms)
```

So I think we need to rule out emulation before we dive into any further debugging.

For reference I am using the following JDK:

```
openjdk version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.4+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.4+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Installed via `brew install openjdk`

Comment: Thanks, I have checked and process is showing Apple in the kind. I have added details in the description. It will be interesting to see how long it takes on your machine to load the same triple in TDB dataset. To load the triple I create a .ttl file and use UI to load the data in empty dataset.